# dynamic add (table or div) rows and columns / how can I do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I need your help.
I have done the visual process I wanted to do. By visual, how do I get this structure using AngularJS? The data will be kept as Json.

In which direction "+" is clicked, the fields in that direction will multiply. These processes can be infinite.

Thank you in advance.

Visual
![img](
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/nbKGVkbv9jTIUMIPXfu4tusKWY4Qzt5TDSLzhLKfG4kuV0oAVio1Q2ZyP-r1wmklMKRnnliI-F_eovLI_1ovWzEQseK6t6ePxcpO2RW5Y3zgJeac-_yWZ5q)

Comment: Show an example of what you have so far, the community can help from there.

Comment: Hello, there is an example that I have not done yet.
I asked for help on how to do this. I couldn't find a healthy solution):
Thanks.

Comment: It might help if you provided a simple example of code here, instead of linking to a third-party site, to better frame what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: As I said, I haven't created a code structure yet. Because I don't know what to do.
):

Answer (score 2):

An option is to create a matrix data structure like

```
var mtrx = [
  [a11, a12],
  [a21, a22],
];
```

then you could bind this structure to a DOM using ngRepeat

```
<div class="files" ng-repeat="file in mtrx">
     <div class="cols" ng-repeat="col in file">
     </div>
</div>
```

Then, to control de dimensions of the matrix you just need to control de data structure.